# How to formulate for loop here

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, element

I have a csv file of information of car (price, model, color, and more)
I have uploaded this into R through read.csv
Some variables are text based categorical variables such as Model, color, and fuel type
I came up with a for loop to find out how to find these text based categorical variables

```
for(i in 1:dim(car)[2]){ 
  if(is.character(car[,i])){
  print(names(car)[i])
  }
}
```

###car is name of file
Now I want to add to the loop how to find the index of the column. For example column of Model is 2 but how should I integrate it into this loop? Below is what I have so far but response is "Integer(0)".

```
for(i in 1:dim(car)[2]){ 
  if(is.character(car[,i])){ 
    print(which(i==colnames(car)))}
}
```

Comment: Note that the `read.csv` function has a `stringsAsFactors` parameter.  You could set that to `TRUE` if you want to read in your character data directly as factors.  See the `read.csv` help to customize by column.

Answer (score 2):

`dim(car)[2]` is the number of columns of `car`. (`ncol()` is a more common way to get this number for a data frame).

`1:dim(car)[2]` is therefore `1, 2, 3, ...` up to the number of columns.

So `for(i in ...)` means `i` will be 1, then `i` will be 2, .... up to the number of columns.

When your `if` statement is `TRUE`, the current value of `i` is the column number. So you want `print(i)` inside your `if()` statement.

Your attempt, `print(which(i==colnames(car)))` failes because `colnames(car)` are the **names** of the columns, and `i` is the **number** of the column. Names and numbers are different.

A more R-like way to do this would be to use `sapply` instead of a loop. Something like this:

```
char_cols = sapply(cars, is.character)
char_cols # named vector saying if each column is character or not
char_cols[char_cols] # look only at the character columns
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. This is a question from an assignment and we have to only modify the loop. However with your comment about "i" being a number I modified my loop and I believe it works now.

Answer (score 0):

"which" function can still be used. From the response from Gregor Thomas there is a way to modify there is a way to modify for loop

```
for(i in 1:ncol(car)){ 
  if(is.character(car[,i])){ 
  print(names(car)[i])
  print(which(names(car)[i]==colnames(car)))
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bavJf.png)

- we first print the actual names through **print(names(car)[i])**
- then we simply ask R to print the names (that we receive above) that match with name in column of "car" dataset

check the link below for a picture. Once again thank you to Mr. Gregor Thomas

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of Gregor Thomas' smart recommendation is to use `sapply` with the `typeof` function to type every column and then the `which` function to get the character column numbers:

```
x <- sapply(cars, typeof)
y <- which(x == 'character')
```

Also note that you see which columns are character from a visual inspection of a dataframe's structure, `str(car)`